# What can cause screen flickering in monitor?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

I have the exact same problem as the guy made [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNVFPC2M7Jo) video.

The laptop (a 17' acer) starts normally and after around 10-20 minutes starts doing this. The screen is ok and suddenly blinks for some milliseconds and then back on and again after 1-3 seconds and so on.

I've replaced the monitor's inverter but still no luck. I connected another laptop screen using the inverter's output and the other monitor also flickered. I believe that after a while something gets heated up and resistance is increased, causing this phenomenon.

At the moment there seem to be three causes for this:

1. Faulty screen cable. This laptop has one cable both for the inverter power and the screen data.
2. The VGA chip (unlikely)
3. The main power to the laptop isn't stable (because of a faulty charger maybe) and causes the inverter to have insufficient power to keep the lid lighting.

I believe I should start with the cable but since I've already bought a part I would like to be sure this time.

Is there a way to check that it is not the cable and if no is there any way to identify the problem at all?

Comment: Does the screen feel abnormally hot when this happens? Have you tried using compressed air to clean the inside of laptop?

Comment: @PeterMaxwell The laptop is dissasembled and no dust seems to be near the vents.

Answer (score 3):

Without buying another part, to test these things you would need to:

1. Test the cable on a laptop with the same connection (preferably to your screen).
2. Look up the laptops model number and see if there are GPU problems common to this model, or run something to test the GPU temperature over time. (A fair few laptops have issues with dry/insufficient soldering or heat management).
3. Try a new charger or leave it on battery for a while to see if the problem is with another internal component.

You could also try cleaning out your laptop too, if it requires it.

Hope this helps!